# How to send body with form-data format in mocha chai

Tags: node.js, api, mocha.js, chai, supertest

This is my headers postman:

[image]

This is my body form-data in postman:

[image]

I am already trying like this

```js
describe('test', function() {
  describe('Get User Data', function() {
    it.only('bla bla bla', function(done) {
      // Send some Form Data
      chai
        .request(app)
        .post('/user/login')
        .send({ username: 'ihdisetiawan', password: 'testing123' })
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('x-api-key', '1234567890')
        .end(function(err, res) {
          expect(res.status).to.equal(responseMessageCode.successOk);
          // expect(res.password).to.equal("testing123");
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

the response get 422

```
Uncaught AssertionError: expected 422 to equal 200
      + expected - actual

      -422
      +200
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) middleware for handling the request payload with `multipart/form-data` content type.
Besides, your case only handle a text-only multipart form, you should use the `.none()` method of `multer`.

E.g.

`server.ts`:

```js
import express from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const upload = multer();
app.post('/user/login', upload.none(), (req, res) => {
  console.log('username:', req.body.username);
  console.log('password:', req.body.password);
  console.log('content-type:', req.get('Content-Type'));
  console.log('x-api-key:', req.get('x-api-key'));
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

if (require.main === module) {
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

export { app };
```

`server.test.ts`:

```js
import { app } from './server';
import request from 'supertest';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('test', () => {
  describe('Get User Data', () => {
    it('bla bla bla', (done) => {
      request(app)
        .post('/user/login')
        .field({
          username: 'ihdisetiawan',
          password: 'testing123',
        })
        .set('x-api-key', '1234567890')
        .end((err, res) => {
          expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

integration test results with coverage report:

```sh
  test
    Get User Data
username: ihdisetiawan
password: testing123
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------481112684938590474892724
x-api-key: 1234567890
      ✓ bla bla bla (47ms)


  1 passing (66ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |   86.67 |       50 |      50 |   86.67 |                   
 server.ts |   86.67 |       50 |      50 |   86.67 | 16,17             
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: how can we mock the form data by just using the req object without having to go through chai routes? In my use case, I am trying to test the controller class not the routes